# How important are registry ROOT menu entries

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-registry

I ‘m doing a fresh install of Windows 7 on another PC. Before making an image backup I do a clean-up of the junk.

After using **ShellNewHandler** to remove unwanted **New** context menu entries. I discovered Adobe was recreating/activating its entry every time I opened Photoshop.
I removed the **ShellNew** entry from the registry root tree manually. Alas, Adobe just kept recreating it.

Eventually I discovered that changing the **.psd** root entry label, removed the offending entry.
Method as follows:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/.psd
Click on .psd
Right click Default in left hand pane and select Modify.
Change PhotoShopImage9 to Photoshop.

I’m just curious how important this root key is, and if changing it should have any adverse future effects. Photoshop appears to run just fine.

Comment: Stop clearing entries out of the registers it’s unnecessary. Your system absolutely will not run faster, or be more stable, the key is important but it obviously won’t prevent Windows from booting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/.psd` is not harmful.

It just tells Windows how to handle `.psd` files, mostly as regarding
Explorer. It defines the icon to be displayed next to such files and
the action to do when double-clicked.

Removing it will prevent Photoshop to add itself to the context menu
of `.psd` files, but it will still be added to the menu for other
image file-types.

I seriously recommend against removing it. Destroying file-associations
in the registry is not a good idea.

Comment: I,m not removing this entry. Only changing the label name. I removed the shellnew entry  which is harmless. However Adobe kept replacing it. My intention was to remove Photoshop from the right click New context menu. Changing the label achieved this.

Comment: The question is if the icon in Explorer next to `.psd` images was changed by the rename and if double-click of the image still opens Photoshop.

Comment: Note: You're not cleaning the registry, just corrupting the Photoshop registry.

Comment: Didn't check that. Yes, icon gone and no longer opens. Will have to rename and live with Photoshop  entry in New context menu.